# global header.php not displaying a certain image on random pages

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm working on a website that was originally built using codeigniter. It's a mess on the back end and there's no identifiers to anything really. I've recently changed a banner (header.php) and edited the style to fit as required. I added a simple img source= and a href= into the header.php and it seems to be displaying fine on the homepage. However once I navigate away to other pages the img source isn't displaying whilst all my other changes are?

The a href link remains with the class but the image is displaying as broken.

I've checked all the locations etc and it's all pointing to the correct place?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code or point us to a working URL etc, so that we can help better. However, check whether the website is using any cache module or not. If yes, try to load the other pages clearing the cache.

Comment: http://www.balmersgm.com/ - is working

http://www.balmersgm.com/static_pages/information/parts - isn't working.

I wonder if it has anything to do with store.php?

Comment: @Aaron, we cant see the PHP through your website.

Comment: <?php  $timezone = date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); ?>

 <div id="header">
    <div class="tagline">
    <a href="<?=base_url()?>"><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/logo_new.png" alt="Balmers" /></a><p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
    <div class="john_deere">
  <a href="http://balmers.jd-dealer.co.uk"><img src="images/john_deere_header.png" alt="Balmers" /></a><p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>

My issue is that the class="john_deere" section that relates to the logo at the top right of the banner only display on certain pages.

Comment: @AaronGorton - can you please edit that into your question? It's much more readable there than in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you have given relative path to your image directory. You have to prepend base_url in src tag as follows

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/path/to/image.jps');?>" alt="Image"/>
```

Comment: This just removes it from all of the banners. Why doesn't it pull the image through on some pages yet it does on others?

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console. Find 404 error for your image, paste it over here.

Comment: It's appending the URL location.

http://www.balmersgm.com**/static_pages/information/**images/john_deere_header.png

base_url doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: So, I am correct. You have given relative path. It should be full url. `<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/path/to/image.jpg" alt="Image"/>`

Comment: `<div class="john_deere">
<a href="http://balmers.jd-dealer.co.uk">
<img src="images/john_deere_header.png" alt="Balmers"/>
</a>
<p/>
</div>`

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/john_deere_header.png" alt="Image"/>`

Comment: Nope. Still not working on anything with **static_pages/information**. Cleared cache....

Comment: Try this then `<div class="john_deere"> <a href="http://balmers.jd-dealer.co.uk"> <img src="http://balmers.jd-dealer.co.uk/images/john_deere_header.png" alt="Balmers"/> </a> <p/> </div>`